# Declaring set in CPLEX

Tags: set, cplex

I am new here and have been trying to write the below equation in CPLEX please help. I tried writing in this way but it is giving an error that says E[i] is not array type

[set equation(click to open)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGyCx.png)

```
int m=... ;
range I= 1..m;
int b[I]=... ;
int w[I]= ... ;
int W =...;

int q= min(i in I)w[i] ;
{int} Y= {y|y in 0..W-q , i in I, E[i] in 0..b[i]: sum(i in I)E[i]*w[i] } ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Slicing with a sum does not work but you can write

```
int m=3 ;
range I= 1..m;
int w[i in I]=i;
int q= min(i in I)w[i] ;
int b[i in I]=2*i;
int W=10;


int bmax=max(i in I)b[i];
int ok[i in I][E in 0..bmax]=(sum(i in I)E*w[i]<=10);

{int} Y= {x|x in 0..W-q , i in I, E in 0..b[i]: ok[i][E]==1 } ;

execute
{
  writeln(Y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Alex. What exactly is the role of ok[i][E]==1 ? Shouldn't E be initialized as E[i] and why should sum(i in I)E*w[i]<=10 , plz explain?

Comment: The goal of ok is have a condition with sum in the slicing part.

Comment: I want to take E in 0 .. b[i] and not in 0..bmax  . How can that be done?

Comment: That's what is done in {int} Y= {x|x in 0..W-q , i in I, E in 0..b[i]: ok[i][E]==1 } ; We take E in 0..b[i]

Comment: As per the code when i=1, E will vary between 0 to bmax (i.e b=6 for i=3). But ideally it should vary only between 0 to b1 (i.e. b1=2 for i=1). Please tell me how to make that change?

Comment: plz answer @alex fleischer